# How to update live activity contents when app terminates

Tags: swift, terminate

I have applied below logic:
[Can I make an api call when the user terminates the app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55234914/can-i-make-an-api-call-when-the-user-terminates-the-app) to fetch contents from the API to update liveActivity when app terminates

Is it a feasible solution?

**Code snippet-**

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. As an advice for your first question, it should focus on the bare problem you’re trying to solve to get more feedback, in this case executing a web request when the application is terminated. The title must reflect that more clearly and the content should set a bit more context and why you want to achieve that. Also, your code snippet should be written inside your post instead of inserted as an image, it helps other people and search engines to find your question.

Comment: If the user terminates the app they are likely not interested in live updates.

Comment: you can start a live activity when the app is the foreground, update it when the app is in fore or background.
If you terminate the app you can not update it. you can use e.g silent push or background tasks to update it in background but no way to update if you kill the app.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a remote push notification to update the live activity when the app is killed by the following the below steps. It is very similar to a regular remote push notification but with few changes:

1- You will need to configure the request headers:

- **apns-topic** with a value of "{APNS_TOPIC}.push-type.liveactivity"
- **apns-push-type** with a value of "liveactivity"
- **authorization** with a value of "bearer {JWT}"
- **Content-Type** with a value of "application/json"

{APNS_TOPIC} should be your app Bundle ID

2- You will need to send the following in the payload:

```
      {
        "aps":{
           "timestamp":1673300490, 
           "event":"update", 
        "content-state":{
           "progress": "10"
        }, 
        "alert":{
           "title":"Update",
           "body":"My Live Activity has been updated remotely" }
        } 
      }
```

3- To end the live activity, you should replace "update" with "end" and add a new parameter below it called "dismissal-date", which should be in epoch time. Note that if you put a time in the past it will be destroyed immediately.

That's it! After sending this push notification from your server, your live activity should be updated accordingly.